# about Lunar lander in Android (inner class)

Tags: android

I am very new to android.

Also very new to java, so please feel free to give me any advice, I would very appreciate it.

the question is in lunarlander.java

```
/** A handle to the thread that's actually running the animation. */
private LunarThread mLunarThread;

/** A handle to the View in which the game is running. */
private LunarView mLunarView;
```

but in lunarview.java

```
class LunarView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
private Context mContext;

/** Pointer to the text view to display "Paused.." etc. */
private TextView mStatusText;


class LunarThread extends Thread
```

I have only learned C and C++

so i can't figure it out why can I call a inner class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes and fields without modifiers private or protected can be accessible from any class in the same package. We can access `LunarThread` by `LunarView.LunarThread` or import class `LunarThread` as done in LunarLander.java:

```
import com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView.LunarThread;
```

See any book about Java for references.